# Simplest way to have my python program store/retrieve information from an online database?

Tags: python, mysql-python

My python program is a lab chemical program, it will be installed on many different computers in several different labs. All of these programs will need to be able to store information to the same online database and retrieve information from this same online database. What is the SIMPLEST way for me to achieve this?

I have considered using MySQLdb but the problem is:

- I am running python on the CLIENT not the SERVER, I have to edit the my.ini file on the SERVER (which I don't have access to) in order to allow remote connections from CLIENTS

What are some simple options here?

Comment: There are a lot of unknowns here.  Do you mean that you already have a server with an online database in which you need to store the data, or that you need to create a database to store the data?  Do you have a server?  What level of control do you have over it?

Comment: I don't know what kind of data your application is going to be handling, but if you can't have enough control over a machine to set up a simple REST interface to a central database of some kind you could always go the p2p route. [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org) has excellent peering capabilities so you could have your program instances sync with each other (using DesktopCouch or something). Honestly, though, p2p is a lot of overhead when you could just get permission to run a simple web server for your application to talk to.

Comment: @BrenBarn My current plan is to register with a website hosting plan like inmotion or something. They will give me a MySQL database. I want my program to be able to connect to this database to store/retrieve data. Do most hosting plans allow me to allow remote host connection to my database? If so, where is the ini file that I need to edit?

Comment: @MeLikeyCode, typically a web host lets you administer and configure the database using something like phpMyAdmin. Remote access may still not be allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need a database host that lets you connect remotely, so, before you contract a host, check with them if you can access the database remotely.

If your host does it, you just need to get the information with them to connect to the database server (usually, the host address, a port, a database name, an user and a password).

Then, create a python file (ex. database.py) to store these information.

Finally, in your program, import these information to create a connection.

Typically you would have:

```
"""
database.py: provides information to make a database connection
"""
login_info = {
    "host":"host_adress",
    "user":"user_name",
    "password":"very_secret_password", 
    "database":"database_name",
    "port": 3306
    }
```

Of course, change the dict values to that you got with your host.

In your program:

```
"""
main_program.py: a chemical program
"""
from database import login_info
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.Connect(**login_info)
curs = conn.cursor()

# STORE
curs.execute("""INSERT INTO table_name(row1,row2) VALUES("foo","bar")""")
conn.commit()

# RETRIVE
curs.execute("""SELECT * FROM table_name""")
results = curs.fetchall()
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Note that I'm using the MySQL Connector/Python driver (and not the MySQLdb driver) that you can get [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/). The MySQL connector has a satisfactory [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html) with code examples that may help you.

Comment: What are the pros/cons of MySQL vs MySQLdb module?

Comment: Both works almost in the same way, since both are PEP 249 compliant. But two advantages from MySQL driver over MySQLdb are: Python 3 support and no dependencies on installation (MySQLdb requires MySQL client libraries, while MySQL driver just need Python installed).

Comment: Perfect, I think I will switch over to using MySQL driver. Thanks for your help, it's much appreciated!

Comment: I've improved code examples about storing and retriving to make the answer more compliant with the question ;)